# Jenkins Build not failing though coverage is below 80%

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, cobertura, coverage.py

Trying to fail Jenkins build even if one of the python test files has less than 80% coverage.
 Towards it, in Jenkins I'm using nosetests to run test coverage on 2 python test files. It prints results as below.  Though one of them has 78% coverage, the build passes. I would want the build to fail in this case
  I have added the Cobertura plugin with post build options as,  Fail builds if no reports, Fail unhealthy builds,  Fail unstable builds. Also set threshold as 80,0,0 for Methods, Packages, Conditionals , Classes & Files.

I tried to run so that total goes below 80 but it still fails.

```
+ nosetests --with-xunit --with-coverage --cover-erase --cover-package=.

Name                        Stmts   Miss  **Cover**

test_sample_script.py           5      0   **100%**
test_sample_script1_80.py       9      2    **78%**

TOTAL                          14      2    **86%**

Ran 2 tests in 0.110s

OK
+ python3 -m coverage xml
[Cobertura] Publishing Cobertura coverage report...

[Cobertura] Publishing Cobertura coverage results...

[Cobertura] Cobertura coverage report found.

Finished: SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned here : https://github.com/jenkinsci/cobertura-plugin/issues/111#issuecomment-580886792

```
With lineCoverageTargets: '90.0, 80.1, 50': 

Report health as 100% if line coverage > 90%
Report health as 0% if line coverage < 80.1%
Mark build as unstable if line coverage < 50%
```